# Unwanted Color Palette on Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, color-palette

I am having issues with a plot that I have created where I am getting an unwanted additional color palette on the plot.

My script uses to list of data to create a plot with colored points.

```
plt.close('all')
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 1)
fig.set_facecolor('white')
axes.set_ylabel('$dz$ [$\AA$]')
axes.set_xlabel('Time [ns]')
axes.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
axes.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
axes.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
axes.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
axes.tick_params(direction='out')
#axes.set_title('N/A')
axes.set_ylim(-20,10)
axes.set_xlim(0, 90)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('plasma')
colors = [cmap(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, 9)]
# Make Color Bar ------------------------------------------------------
cax = 0
divider = make_axes_locatable(axes)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.1)
im = axes.imshow(np.linspace(1, 8.5, 100).reshape(10, 10), cmap='plasma')
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
for i, dist in enumerate(dz):
    if i % 100 == 0:
        x = i / 1000 
        y = dist
        phval = final_pH_array[i]
        axes.plot(x, y, 'k.', markersize = 4 , color = colors[int(phval)], clip_on = False)
plt.savefig('plot.pdf')
plt.show()
```

The results looks like this:

[image]

As you can see there is an additional color bar / color palette that I don't want on the plot but can't seem to get rid of it.

Any help with this would be great!

Comment: You create this image in your code via the line `im = axes.imshow(...)`. So you need to remove that line. It very much looks as if the colorbar you are creating shows much more colors that you use; i.e. you only use 8 different colors, right? So one would create a colorbar for those 8 colors only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `im.set_visible(False)` should achieve what you want.

But maybe you should take a look at [`plt.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html). `scatter` returns a `PathCollection` that you can pass to the `colorbar` function.